# Update data, but nothing change in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I need help, I am developing an ASP.NET app, there are 2 problems,

Problem #1: when I click the "update" button, it says success, but nothing happened in the database, the data is still the same as before...

Problem #2: when I click select on gridview, all of my input fills with data from database except password input

Here is my code

Update code:

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE datauser SET Password = @b, Nama = @c, Role@d WHERE Username = @a", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", uname.Value.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", pwd.Value.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", nama.Value.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", ddlrole.SelectedItem.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    lblok.Text = "Perbarui " + ddlrole.SelectedItem.Text + " Berhasil";
    okm.Visible = true;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "HideLabel();", true);
    reset();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    con.Close();
    lbleror.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    errm.Visible = true;
}
```

Gridview "SelectionChanged" event:

```
string pas;
GridViewRow gvrow = griduser.SelectedRow;
uname.Value = gvrow.Cells[0].Text.ToString();
pwd.Value= gvrow.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
nama.Value = gvrow.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
ddlrole.SelectedValue = gvrow.Cells[3].Text;
invokeedit();
```

Gridview ASPX markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="griduser" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" 
     CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
     AllowPaging="True" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="griduser_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Nama" HeaderText="Nama" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Role" HeaderText="Role" />
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aksi">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="link" CommandName="Select" ToolTip="Edit" 
                       runat="server" CssClass="icon-edit"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkremove" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Username")%>' 
                       ToolTip="Hapus" runat="server" CssClass="icon-remove" 
                       OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?')"
                       OnClick="hapusdata"></asp:LinkButton>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: As a quick look: shouldn't `Role@d` be `Role = @d` ??

Comment: You should read the return value of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery before thinking that your update has been successful. If the return is zero then no matching record has been found in the database pointed by your connection string. Better check this.

Comment: @S.Akbari, oh yeaa I still slipshod, thx, problem 1 clear...Now there problem 2, it still empty on password field when I press Select command button

Comment: Is this a school project, or a real world application?